# Map folder from container 1 to container 2

Tags: docker

I'm trying to map my folder "/usr/share/nginx/html" from container 1 to "/usr/share/nginx/html" from container 2, in order to show the same files in the container 2.

I know that you can share folders between host and containers with "-v folder:/usr/share/nginx/html", but i couldn't find a way to do it between containers or with "volumes-from" parameter.

Is this possible to map folders this way?

thanks

Comment: Can you map the same folder on your host to both containers? Then they would both have the same contents and changes on one would happen to the other. If you do not want to have a folder on the host machine maybe use docker volumes (`docker volume create myvolume` and the add `-v myvolume:/usr/share/nginx/html` to both docker run commands)

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to mount a directory from inside one container into another container.

But if the data is stored outside of the container - e.g. on the host filesystem or nfs drive, you can either [bind-mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) or [volume-mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) that storage into both containers.